# Map drive is not recognized by my application in windows 8, 8.1 and windows 10

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, mfc, windows-8.1

I am not able to retrieve map drive  when I run my application as an administrator. I am logged in as other user having administrative privilege. When I run my application without run as administrator  map drive is shown. I want to show the map drive when I run my application as run as administrator. Please provide me the solution for this it only happens when I run my application in windows 8,8.1 and windows 10. I have developed my application in visual studio 2010 using vc++.

Answer (score 2):

This is the normal behaviour (that I don't like) since Windows Vista.

You need to set EnableLinkedConnections in the registry. You find the background of this in this [article](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ee844140%28v=ws.10%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

If your program needs this access you are forced to change this value in your  installer.

Comment: i already change the registry  EnableLinkedConnections but it not working .

Comment: You have to remap the links. If the session was already created without the mapped files you have to redo it..

Comment: it is mandatory to remap the links .is there any another way to retrieve the mapped drive without  remapped it.

Comment: Mapped network drives are designed for the convenience of *end users*, not application programmers. If you need to access a network resource, use the UNC path. You won't have any problems then.